# Create a new column grouping numbers (num) to new created groups of Factors

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame with a Vector/column of numbers **-60 to 300** and I would like to create a new column with groups in it from that column e.g.

group from

```
-30 to 30 = "Trans",
 31 to 100 = "Early", 
101 to 200 = "Mid", 
201 - 300 = "Late" 
else = "NA"
```

Not sure if I need to use `dplyr:mutate or group_by`
Any help would be very much appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, here you tell us what you have tried and failed, then we all come in to help

Answer (score 2):

This is one way you could do it

```
id= -30:300 # create vector -30 to 300
df <- data.frame(id) # make it a dataframe
b <- c(-30, 30, 100, 200, 300, Inf) # create a vector of break points:
grp <- c("trans", "early", "mid","late", "na") # create vector names of breakpoint

df$group <- cut(df$id, breaks = b, labels = grp)
df
```

```
    id group1
1   -30   <NA>
2   -29  trans
3   -28  trans
.....
60   29  trans
61   30  trans
62   31  early
63   32  early
64   33  early
.....
130  99  early
131 100  early
132 101    mid
133 102    mid
134 103    mid
.....
230 199    mid
231 200    mid
232 201   late
233 202   late
.....
330 299   late
331 300   late
```